# PostgreSQL Calls All Data For Group By Limit Operation

Tags: postgresql, indexing, group-by, query-optimization, limit

I have a query like below:

```sql
SELECT 
    MAX(m.org_id) as orgId,
    MAX(m.org_name) as orgName,
    MAX(m.app_id) as appId,
    MAX(r.country_or_region) as country, 
    MAX(r.local_spend_currency) as currency, 
    SUM(r.local_spend_amount) as spend,
    SUM(r.impressions) as impressions
    ...
FROM report r  
LEFT JOIN metadata m 
    ON m.org_id = r.org_id
    AND m.campaign_id = r.campaign_id
    AND m.ad_group_id = r.ad_group_id 
WHERE (r.report_date BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-10-10') 
    AND r.org_id = 1
GROUP BY r.country_or_region, r.ad_group_id, r.keyword_id, r.keyword, r.text  
OFFSET 0
LIMIT 20
```

Explain Analyze:

```
"Limit  (cost=1308.04..1308.14 rows=1 width=562) (actual time=267486.538..267487.067 rows=20 loops=1)"
"  ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=1308.04..1308.14 rows=1 width=562) (actual time=267486.537..267487.061 rows=20 loops=1)"
"        Group Key: r.country_or_region, r.ad_group_id, r.keyword_id, r.keyword, r.text"
"        ->  Sort  (cost=1308.04..1308.05 rows=1 width=221) (actual time=267486.429..267486.536 rows=567 loops=1)"
"              Sort Key: r.country_or_region, r.ad_group_id, r.keyword_id, r.keyword, r.text"
"              Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 667552kB"
"              ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.13..1308.03 rows=1 width=221) (actual time=0.029..235158.692 rows=2742789 loops=1)"
"                    ->  Nested Loop Semi Join  (cost=0.44..89.76 rows=1 width=127) (actual time=0.016..8.967 rows=1506 loops=1)"
"                          Join Filter: (m.org_id = (479360))"
"                          ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.44..89.05 rows=46 width=123) (actual time=0.013..4.491 rows=1506 loops=1)"
"                                ->  HashAggregate  (cost=0.02..0.03 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=1 loops=1)"
"                                      Group Key: 479360"
"                                      ->  Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=1 loops=1)"
"                                ->  Index Scan using pmx_org_cmp_adg on metadata m  (cost=0.41..88.55 rows=46 width=119) (actual time=0.008..1.947 rows=1506 loops=1)"
"                                      Index Cond: (org_id = (479360))"
"                          ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..0.03 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=1 loops=1506)"
"                                ->  Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.000..0.000 rows=1 loops=1)"
"                    ->  Index Scan using report_unx on search_term_report r  (cost=0.69..1218.26 rows=1 width=118) (actual time=51.983..155.421 rows=1821 loops=1506)"
"                          Index Cond: ((org_id = m.org_id) AND (report_date >= '2019-07-01'::date) AND (report_date <= '2019-10-10'::date) AND (campaign_id = m.campaign_id) AND (ad_group_id = m.ad_group_id))"
"Planning Time: 0.988 ms"
"Execution Time: 267937.889 ms"
```

I have indexes on metadata and report table like: metadata(org_id, campaign_id, ad_group_id); report(org_id, report_date, campaign_id, ad_group_id)

1. I just want to call random 20 items with limit. But PostgreSQL takes so long time to call it? How can I improve it?

Answer (score 0):

You want to have 20 groups. But for building these groups (to be sure, there is nothing missing in any group), you need to fetch all raw data.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "random items", I assume you mean "random reports", as you have no item table.

```
with r as (select * from report WHERE r.report_date BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-10-10' AND r.org_id = 1 order by random() limit 20)
select <whatever> from r left join <whatever>
```

You might need to tweak your aggregates a but.  Does every record in "metadata" belong to exactly one record in "report"?